# Simple question: Can x86 apps take advantage of the extra RAM a x64 OS gives?

Tags: windows-7, x86, 64-bit, upgrade, windows-7-x64

I hope someone with a bit of knowledge can clear this up. There's many discussions about the reasons to run a 64-bit OS (e.g. Windows 7 x64), but many people seem to think that their old x86 apps will be able to take advantage of any RAM greater than 3.5GB.

As I understand it, though, x86 apps cannot address memory that high... unless they've been specifically programmed to (which very few will have).

Can someone knowledgeable clear this up for me, once and for all? Can 32-bit apps take advantage of a system running 8GB of RAM?

E.g. If a user decided (for whatever reason) to run several x86 apps at once, filling the RAM as much as possible, would the extra addressable memory available in **Windows 7 x64** be used?

Thanks!

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a 64 bit system, 32 bit applications are able to use the full 4GB virtual address space, minus about 64K. A default 32 bit windows system will only allow a 32 bit process to use 2 GB of virtual address space. By specially configuring the OS it's possible to push that limit up to 3 GB, but it's still not as good as what you would get on a 64 bit version of windows.

If you have 8GB of ram, that 8 GB can be divided up between multiple 32 bit processes, and the entire 8 GB will be utilized if necessary. However, no single 32 bit process will be allocated more than 4 GB of memory.

Answer (score 3):

Although i don't have sources to cite, but from my knowledge: 32bit app will not be able to address more than 4GB of memory itself, unless it uses some tricks(that is very unlikely), but if you have some 32bit apps running at the same time, they can all have 4GB each, and thus two 32bit apps should be able to use all 8GB of memory. Though I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Be 100% sure. That's one of the benefits of a virtual address space.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  x86 apps cannot use more than 2GB of memory at once without special tricks, but they can use any memory available.

Comment: @Gabe: Yes, I would say so—normal apps don't have it.

Comment: True, but you don't have to recompile.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the other (correct) answers:

1. Instead of the term "application" the word "process" should be used. Applications often consist of multiple processes whereas the limits discussed here apply to single processes.
2. Thus applications benefit from x64 that either are linked with the LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag (they can use 4 GB instead of 2 GB) or that share the load between multiple processes.
3. 32-bit processes can work with more than 4 GB RAM even on 32-bit systems by using AWE. But a 32-bit process can only ever use 2 GB *at once* (4 GB with LARGEADDRESSAWARE on 64 bit respectively). AWE is primarily used by databases where it is essential for performance that the entire database fit into RAM. It works by providing a 2 GB window into a larger chunk of memory.

Here are some articles for further reading:

[Windows x64 – All the Same Yet Very Different, Part 1: Virtual Memory](http://helgeklein.com/blog/2008/01/windows-x64-all-the-same-yet-very-different-part-1/)

[Windows x64 – All the Same Yet Very Different, Part 2: Kernel Memory, /3GB, PTEs, (Non-) Paged Pool](http://helgeklein.com/blog/2008/01/windows-x64-all-the-same-yet-very-different-part-2/)

[x64? My Terminal Servers Run Just Fine With 32 Bits and 8/12/16 GB RAM!](http://helgeklein.com/blog/2008/05/x64-my-terminal-servers-run-just-fine-with-32-bits-and-81216-gb-ram/)

Answer (score 1):

> E.g. If a user decided (for whatever
>   reason) to run several x86 apps at
>   once, filling the RAM as much as
>   possible, would the extra addressable
>   memory available in Windows 7 x64 be
>   used?

The answer is yes.  That's one of the benefits a virtual address space gives us--the ability for each process to appear (to the process) as though it's executing in a linear address space that starts at 0 and goes up from there.

As far as each of the 32-bit applications is concerned, it has its own address space from 0 to 2 gigabytes (without special tricks).  The operating system handles the virtual-to-physical address translation.